# Exit code: 139 plugin SQLplus Jenkins o que é este erro?

Tags: oracle, jenkins

Estou com um jenkins funcionando a algum tempo porem necessitamos de fazer as builds integradas com o Oracle então usei o SQLPlus Script Runner, e esta ocorrendo um ero ja procurei em diversos locais mas nada me da uma ideia do motivo do erro segue:

Setting JDK1_8_192_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK1-8-192
[43] $ /opt/oracle_11/client_1/bin/sqlplus -L user/pass@DB @/tmp/temp-script-15410242206632532672140431784649.sql
Process exited with status 139

Exit code: 139

texto em negritojava.lang.RuntimeException: Process exited with error
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplus.script.runner.SQLPlusRunner.run(SQLPlusRunner.java:446)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplus.script.runner.SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.perform(SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java:174)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Process exited with error
Finished: FAILURE

As variáveis estão todas definidas ORACLE_HOME, PATH, TNS_ADMIN

Alguem teria uma ideia da causa ?

Comment: Problema resolvido

Reinstalei as libs libaio libaio-devel libaio-devel libstdc++ elfutils-libelf-devel sysstat libgcc unixODBC unixODBC-devel compat-libstdc++ compat-libstdc++

Refiz a configuração da variável ORACLE_HOME e TNS_ADMIN e o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido;

Reinstalei as libs:> libaio libaio-devel libaio-devel libstdc++ elfutils-libelf-devel sysstat libgcc unixODBC unixODBC-devel compat-libstdc++ compat-libstdc++

Refiz a configuração da variável ORACLE_HOME e TNS_ADMIN e o problema foi resolvido.

fiz o teste de reinstalar o Oracle através do arquivo de instalação do próprio site da Oracle apenas por desencargo de confidencia, após a reinstalação dessas libs.